# How to find id according to variable?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a series of 11 TextViews in my app. They all have the IDs as text_1, text_2,...

I also have an int named start, which is a number between 1 and 11.

I have initialized the Variables of TextViews as text1, text2, and so on but I have not assigned their ID.

Now, I want that text1(the variable) should be assigned the id R.id.text_(the value of start)
How to do that?

Here's my code so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView text1;
    TextView text2;
    TextView text3;
    TextView text4;
    TextView text5;
    TextView text6;
    TextView text7;
    TextView text8;
    TextView text9;
    TextView text10;
    TextView text11;
    private placeNames[] placeBank = new placeNames[]{
            new placeNames(R.string.place1, 5),
            new placeNames(R.string.place2, 6),
            new placeNames(R.string.place3, 5),
            new placeNames(R.string.place4, 6),
            new placeNames(R.string.place5, 7)
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void newGame(View view){
        int randomNum = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(Math.random() * 6));
        String placeName = getPlaceData(randomNum)[0];
        int placeLength = Integer.parseInt(getPlaceData(randomNum)[1]);
        ArrayList<String> letters = null;
        for (int i = 1; i>=placeName.length();i++){
            letters.add(String.valueOf(placeName.charAt(i)));
        }
        String start = String.valueOf(getStartView(placeLength));
        text1 = findViewById(R.id.)
    }

    public String[] getPlaceData(int id){
        int length = placeBank[id].getLength();
        String name = String.valueOf(placeBank[id].getPlaceId());
        String[] result = {name, String.valueOf(length)};
        return result;
    }
    public int getStartView(int length){
    int result = (11 - length)/2;
    return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't a particularly well-written question so I recommend you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
It is impossible to answer your question properly with the information given. That is why nobody has answered. Also, I would advise you to do a little research because I instantly found docs on TextView just by searching "TextView Android Studio". [TextView Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView) EDIT: You should add some example code as well.

Comment: @KNOBPersonal Please see edited question

Comment: Tell me if I understood you. You want to asign TextView's ID's from the Activity Java class and not from the xml??

Comment: @LuisAguilar The IDs are in the xml only, but which ID to assign, that has to be decided according to the value of int start.

Comment: @DeathVenom Can you please provide the code you have written until now?

Comment: Basically, he wants to assign ID using strin as `findViewById(R.id.valueOfString)` so if this `valueOfString` is `text1`, it can call `R.id.text1`. I don't think it's possible, even if it is, it can cause problems like NPE at runtime of which he'd have no control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood by your question is you do not want to use switch/when cases and wants to keep your code short, clean and simple.

For that, I would suggest you to go with `FindViewWithTag` because you can pass string in it programmatically. **Here's how:**

First, set tag to every view you have just like you do to set ID by using `android:tag="yourtag"`.

Then, you can initialize it in your code as:

```
String str = "MyTag1" //or for 2nd TextView "MyTag2", "MyTag3"
TextView textView = view.findViewWithTag(string);
```

Now, this TextView will be initialized without using swtich case but remember to match the format of this tag with what stored in XML file. Also, use a counter type mechanism to change this suffix integer as your TextView as 11 for TextView 11.

Some tips:

- This findViewWithTag uses a view, you can't directly call finyViewWithTag so in this case you have a view, but anywhere else you have to initialize its parent element as view.
- Also, you can use string resources to assign a tag as you can use string resources in xml as well to assign a tag and then can call it like

  ```
  if(i==7) {
      String tag = getResources().getString(R.string.myTag7);
      textview = view.finyViewWithTag(tag);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you need but, based on your question I guess this is it:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private int start = 2; //Any int number from 1 to 11

private TextView text1;
private TextView text2;
private TextView text3;
private TextView text4;
private TextView text5;
private TextView text6;
private TextView text7;
private TextView text8;
private TextView text9;
private TextView text10;
private TextView text11;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    switch (start){

        case 1:
            text1 = findViewById(R.id.text_1);
            break;

        case 2:
            text2 = findViewById(R.id.text_2);
            break;

        case 3:
            text3 = findViewById(R.id.text_3);
            break;

        case 4:
            text4 = findViewById(R.id.text_4);
            break;

        case 5:
            text5 = findViewById(R.id.text_5);
            break;

        case 6:
            text6 = findViewById(R.id.text_6);
            break;

        case 7:
            text7 = findViewById(R.id.text_7);
            break;

        case 8:
            text8 = findViewById(R.id.text_8);
            break;

        case 9:
            text9 = findViewById(R.id.text_9);
            break;

        case 10:
            text10 = findViewById(R.id.text_10);
            break;

        case 11:
            text11 = findViewById(R.id.text_11);
            break;

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Yes, that is an option. However, I was searching for a shorter and more efficient piece of code. If I don't get any other way, I'll use this.

Comment: If you only initialize the ID of one TextView in your activity. I don't see why you need to declare the rest of them.